# Class Controller not found in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

So I am new to laravel and was just trying out some code to clear the basics,but however after creating a new controller to handle a route.It throws a fatal exception saying Class 'Controller' not found!

(The controller.php exists in the same directory)

The controller.php code is the default one

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

This is my PagesController.php code

```
<?php

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        $name = 'Yeah!';
        return View::make('welcome')->with('name',$name);
    }
}
```

This is route.php code

```
<?php

Route::get('/','PagesController@home');
```

The welcome.blade.php code is the default one except it displays the variable $name instead of laravel 5.
What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Make sure your controller is namespaced as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you reference a class like `extends Controller` PHP searches for the class in your **current namespace**.

In this case that's a global namespace. However the `Controller` class obviously doesn't exists in global namespace but rather in `App\Http\Controllers`.

You need to specify the namespace at the top of `PagesController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Comment: I tried that and the controller works,but now as the namespace is the controller directory,I get an error view not found.Any other options

Comment: @gospelslide you can either add `use View;` to the top of controller or use alias `view` like this: `return view('welcome')->with('name', $name);`

Answer (score 2):

You will want to specify the namespace to your `Controller` class:

```
class PagesController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

otherwise `Controller` is looked up in the default root namespace `\`, where it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a different class name than the one in the class that extends controller, the names should be same

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a controller inside a subfolder with a different namespace then use this on your controller file:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your routes/web.php, use the namespace for the PagesController eg.

```
<?php
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller\PagesController;

  Route::get('/','PagesController@home');
```

This will enable you to access the PagesController class.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I could not use controllers I created, it worked after i used the controller with its full path:

```
Route::get('/pizzas/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\PizzaController::class, 'show']);
```

the `use` function at the top of the `web.php` file did not work